# Worry about a lot of event listener in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm a new member of this site. I am making a game where I need to use a lot event listeners.

**Problem:**
 
There'll be around 300 event listeners in my game, I'm worried about if this will affect my game?

Comment: I did not down-vote you but this is not a good question (_eg:_ how to answer when put like this?). (1) What effect are you worried about? (2) Did you see any problem from 300 listeners? (3) The listeners must be attached to some object, are you sure the 300 objects (graphics?) themselves don't effect the game?

Comment: If all the event handlers are supposed to be the ENTER_FRAME event handlers, I advise to make the only event listener then distribute the event via your own algorithm (like signal or my Chronos https://bitbucket.org/thydmitry/ru.delimiter/src/2756fadd741a6d44276fde1701470daf24cebfa8/classes/ru/delimiter/events/Chronos.as?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default). If these events are different events from different sources that won't be firing in packs every frame, it will be fine, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will affect your game, primarily because you will need to control all 300 so that they won't create memory leaks in form of defunct (released) objects left in memory because they have a listener attached to say `stage`. Secondary aspect is performance, each listener taking actions is several function calls below the curtains, thus it's better to organize those listeners somehow. It's fine to have a button listen on itself for say `MouseEvent.CLICK` and to have 300 buttons like that, because each time you click only a few (ideally one) listeners would react. It's not as fine to have 300 listeners listen for `Event.ENTER_FRAME` because each frame all of them would be invoked, and it's better to have one listener instead, but every subsystem or every object would then get called from that listener. This approach will also lessen the overhead on Flash event subsystem to direct calls, and lessen your hassle about unattached listeners.

There may be more performance aspects regarding listeners, especially since Flash engine developers started placing security checks into the engine, slowing event processing by a significant margin, these are however obscure and the only thing is known about them is "use fewer listeners". You will still have to rely on Flash event cycle at least on the top level, even if you devise an event processing system of your own, or use a system made by another, but the main point stands, "the fewer, the better". If you can lessen the number of *listeners*, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are very vague on the kind of event listeners you use if they are enterframes it could be a issue try not using enterframs on objects and use them on the stage but if you are using 300.

I'm sure only a subset would be Enter_Frames and most will be mouse events. And i don't think most of them would be on active MovieClips.

So only a subset would be active at a time so mostly nothing to be worried about as long as there isn't any unwanted behaviour. I feel you should be good to go . But do Manage all of your enterframes.